# Missing provisional profile feature when building using fastlane/Jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, fastlane

I'm trying to setup automated iOS builds using Jenking/fastlane. The codesigning was set up using `fastlane match`. However when Jenkins runs the job and invokes `xcodebuild` I'm getting:

```
[16:06:09]: [36m$ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./Runner.xcworkspace -scheme dev -configuration Release-dev -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-04-14/Runner\ 2020-04-14\ 16.06.09.xcarchive archive | tee /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Logs/gym/Runner-dev.log | xcpretty[0m
[16:06:23]: ▸ [35m[31m❌  error: "Runner" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')[0m
[16:06:23]: ▸ [35m** ARCHIVE FAILED **[0m
```

Needless to say the profiles used does contain said feature (I've checked in Developers portal).

My Fastfile (relevant section):

```
  private_lane :build_qa do
    UI.message("Building qa build...")
    sync_code_signing
    sync_code_signing(type: "adhoc", readonly: true)
    update_code_signing_settings(
      use_automatic_signing: false,
      path: "Runner.xcodeproj"
    )
    sh("cd ../..;
      flutter build ios --release --flavor dev --no-codesign"
    )
    build_ios_app(
      scheme: "dev",
      configuration: "Release-dev",
      output_name: "Runner.ipa"
    )
    update_code_signing_settings(
      use_automatic_signing: true,
      path: "Runner.xcodeproj"
    )
  end
```

Summary of `match`:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                           [32mSummary for gym 2.145.0[0m                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| scheme                                                                  | dev                                                               |
| configuration                                                           | Release-dev                                                       |
| output_name                                                             | Runner                                                            |
| catalyst_platform                                                       | ios                                                               |
| export_method                                                           | ad-hoc                                                            |
| export_options.provisioningProfiles.com.flutter.example.track.dev       | match AdHoc com.flutter.example.track.dev                         |
| export_options.provisioningProfiles.com.flutter.example.track.prod      | match AdHoc com.flutter.example.track.prod                        |
| workspace                                                               | ./Runner.xcworkspace                                              |
| destination                                                             | generic/platform=iOS                                              |
| build_path                                                              | /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-05-05 |
| clean                                                                   | false                                                             |
| output_directory                                                        | .                                                                 |
| silent                                                                  | false                                                             |
| skip_package_ipa                                                        | false                                                             |
| result_bundle                                                           | false                                                             |
| buildlog_path                                                           | ~/Library/Logs/gym                                                |
| skip_profile_detection                                                  | false                                                             |
| skip_package_pkg                                                        | false                                                             |
| xcode_path                                                              | /Applications/Xcode.app                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe I'm a little bit late but here there is my working solution:

```
# Initial considerations: we want to have all the control over project settings,
# in particular
# - code signing
# - provisioning
# - team
# - app identifier

platform :ios do
 lane :build do |values|
  # All params should be dynamically passed with ENV vars
  
  # Disable automatic code signing must be set BEFORE match
  disable_automatic_code_signing(
   path: PROJECT_PATH,
   team_id: TEAM_ID
  )
   
   # match action... 
   # In my case app_store_connect_api_key + sync_code_signing
   
   # Provisioning update 
   # NOTE: PROFILE_PATH_ENV_VAR, based on match type, is the provisioning profile path previously generated from match
   # I.e. for development match type: sigh_[appBundleId]_development_profile-path
   # Check https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/xcode-project/#set-using-environment-variable for more info
   update_project_provisioning(
    xcodeproj: XCODE_PROJECT_PATH,
    target_filter: TARGET_NAME,
    profile: ENV["PROFILE_PATH_ENV_VAR"],
    build_configuration: "Release"
   )

   # Project team update
   update_project_team(
    path: XCODE_PROJECT_PATH,
    teamid: TEAM_ID
   )
   
   # App identifier update
   update_app_identifier(
    xcodeproj: XCODE_PROJECT_PATH,
    plist_path: PLIST_PATH,
    app_identifier: BUNDLE_ID
   )
 
   gym(
    # ... Every custom param you need 
    ...
    codesigning_identity: CERTIFICATE_NAME,
    export_options: {
      compileBitcode: false,
      provisioningProfiles: ENV['MATCH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MAPPING'], # ENV var generated from match 
# http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sync_code_signing/#lane-variables
      signingStyle: "manual"
     }
    )
 end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use match to manage the provisioning profiles you can force them in `gym`/`build_ios_app` with `export_options` like these:

```
gym(
  scheme: "dev",
  configuration: "Release-dev",
  output_name: "Runner.ipa"
  export_options: {
    compileBitcode: false,
    provisioningProfiles: ENV['MATCH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MAPPING']
  },
  codesigning_identity: "Certificate name, if you want to override it as well"
)
```

Comment: Do you use match in the lane or did you just launched it one time? I've got the impression that you enabled the Push Capability AFTER match usage. This means that your provisioning doesn't include the Push Capability. I suggest you to add `match` in your lane as first step, with the option `force: true`, to force regeneration of provisioning profile at each run.

Comment: In my case it is `Actions.lane_context[SharedValues::MATCH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MAPPING]` instead of `ENV['MATCH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MAPPING']`